# Spring configure Principal.getname() to return JWT email claim

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm currently getting the email of a user from the `SecurityContextHolder`:

```
Jwt jwt = (Jwt) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
return jwt.getClaims().get("email").toString();
```

Is there a way configure `Principal.getName()` so that it will return the email directly to avoid specific knowledge of the Jwt in the controller? For example:

```
  @PutMapping("/reserve")
  public Object reserveGame(Principal principal) {
    String email = principal.getName(); // need this to return email
    return dao.reserveGame(email);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite your UserDetails class method `getUsername()` and return `email` attribute. Or you can provide a custom `UserAuthenticationConverter`